# Whats the proper way to activate autoincrementation on PostgreSQL primary key?

Tags: postgresql

Starting on using PostgreSQL, I am currently having a situation where my primary gets updated only from the code, but not frm script I am running at init...

I have the 3 following SQL file:

```
// 1.
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO testapi;

// 2.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    name VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS cities_seq_id;
SELECT setval('cities_seq_id', (SELECT max(id)+1 FROM cities), false);
ALTER TABLE cities ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('cities_seq_id');

// 3.
INSERT INTO cities (name)
VALUES ('Barcelona'),
       ('Seville'),
       ('Madrid'),
       ('Valencia'),
       ('Andorra la Vella'),
       ('Malaga');
```

Starting postgreSQL like so:

```
windows: docker run --name postgres -v %cd%\init\database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=testapi -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=packngo -e POSTGRES_DB=testdb -d postgres:14.0
----
linux: docker run --name postgres -v $(pwd)/init/database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=testapi -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=packngo -e POSTGRES_DB=testdb -d postgres:14.0
```

Why am I getting the following (when calling my rest API of course, but result turns out to be the same when I do a SELECT, it's just feel easier to understand):

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Barcelona"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Seville"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Madrid"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Valencia"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Andorra la Vella"
    },
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Malaga"
    }
]
```

I really don't understand.. I tried to update my SQL file to insert ID along names but no success.. any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Your SQL code makes no sense at all, but it certainly won't produce the result you show. You should read the PostgreSQL documentation on `serial` and sequences.

Comment: dates as `varchar(27)` seems very strange.

Comment: What are you running to query your data? [I cannot reproduce your result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f899385f7ff01eb83a750aedcdb1a77f).

Comment: Sorry to both of you if you missunderstood some parts :) I updated my question by specifying that i get back these data from my API as I didn't use any pg UI client but only code :) Anyway, i've checked, the issue isn't coming from here as it is only when I run the insert from these init sql script that I have the issue :) I also removed the parts regarding the trip as it has no links related to the topic, sorry :)

Comment: @Emixam23 Your primary keys are supposed to be unique, so something else is happening you're not showing us. Let's remove the API output, we don't know what that is. Instead, show us the `select` and its result in psql. Also please show us `\d+ cities` from psql so we can see your true table definition.

Comment: My mistake was a rookie mistake.. The docker container wasn't getting recreated and so the script were not consumed :) based on this I was always getting the same results, no matter the edit I was doing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I was unable to reproduce your result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f899385f7ff01eb83a750aedcdb1a77f), there must be something wrong with how you're querying your data.

That said, you can make your schema much simpler.

- You do not need to create your own sequences, [`serial` does that for you](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).
- You do not need to declare your primary keys as unique, primary keys are unique by definition.
- There's little point to arbitrarily limiting the size of text fields in your schema. `varchar(50)` takes up no less space than `text`. Limit them in your business logic. What if someone wants to go to [Llanfair­pwllgwyngyll­gogery­chwyrn­drobwll­llan­tysilio­gogo­goch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llanfairpwllgwyngyll)?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

- Foreign keys should not be `serial`. They do not auto-increment. Use `integer` to refer to a `serial` primary key.
- `price` certainly should not be `serial`. It is presumably an integer or [numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL).
- Storing `dates` as `varchar(27)` is very strange. If it's a list of dates, use a date [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/arrays.html) `date[]`. If it's range of dates use [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rangetypes.html).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trips (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    destination_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES cities,
    origin_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES cities,
    dates DATERANGE NOT NULL,
    price INTEGER NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (destination_id, origin_id)
);
```

Comment: I actually removed that part :) I am tho a bit surprised that both of you looked at the trip.dates part where my issue is related to "city" table id which isn't incrementing :/ However, I do feel that it has no link to the topic, I so removed this part :) sorry if I confused you :) thanks for your answer(s) tho :)

Comment: amazing answer by the way :) I will look into it, thanks for your feedback :) I am quite new to this

Comment: @Emixam23: btw: you might want to consider using `generated always as identity` instead of the [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) serial "type"

Answer (score 0):

I think newer PG versions has something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR ( 50 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` is preferable.